# Is it possible to temporarily transfer ownership of a staked token to another wallet address without unstaking,

Tags: transfer, staking

Is it possible to temporarily transfer ownership of an ERC20 staked token to another wallet address without unstaking, for example if I have wallet address X, and I have staked my tokens with a particular project. However I also have wallet Y and want to transfer ownership of the staked token from Wallet X to Wallet Y without unstaking from the contract or project.

Comment: The staked token is not owned by you, so no.

Comment: Some projects allows transfer of the stake.

Comment: @Ismael for the projects that allows transfer of the stake, do you have an example of a project that allows the transfer of stake

Comment: @ArMoat For example uniswap pools mint an ERC20 token when depositing funds, those tokens can be transferred like any other ERC20 token. The recipient can withdraw the funds from the pool.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the staking contract, but most likely the answer is no.

The answer is no UNLESS the staking contract specifically allows for this, which is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to unstake before being able to transfer ownership.